# Book button not working in Firefox, but working in chrome and explorer?

Tags: html, firefox

I have this weird thing going on with my button.This is my code for the `button` (book button in my website) which is **not working** in `Firefox` but works in google `chrome` and `internet explorer`. Is there anything that i can do to make it work in `Firefox`.

This is my code;

```
    $thisresult = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if($booking_info['check_out'] <= date('Y-m-d')){
        echo    "<button style=' ' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>";
    } 
    else if(mysqli_num_rows($thisresult)>=1){
        echo "You have already booked this hotel!";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<button style=' ' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>"; 
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't put an anchor inside a button.

Comment: well then chrome and internet explorer are wrong because this shouldn't work at all

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by anchor?

Comment: @developerwjk why is that?

Comment: @AmirHD `<a>` is an anchor.

Comment: @developerwjk Since it's invalid HTML, browsers are allowed to interpret it however they want. Which includes making it work.

Comment: Because of what Barmar said.

Comment: i have got rid of them and the button doesn't work now

Comment: As @Barmar says, the anchor inside the button is inappropriate. If you want to make the anchor _look_ like a button, you can style it in CSS. There is, however, another issue here. Without more information to go on, it looks like part of a booking form. In that case, the form should use the POST method, and you should use a proper submit button _without_ an anchor. The URL should be in the form’s `action` property, and the `id` should be in a hidden field.

Comment: You can also use `formaction` in the submit button to set the URL that it submits to.

Comment: Anyway, see the answers in the linked question for suggestions on how to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Manngo i'm confused, is it possible if you can provide me with the code please? I'd appropriate a help, thanks!

Comment: @AmirHD With respect, I think you need to learn more about forms, submitting them, and how PHP process them. @Barmar’s suggestion to look at the duplicated question will answer your immediate question.